# Join on Number Columns with different size

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.mycolumn = table2.mycolumn
```

Type of `table1.mycolumn` is `Number(10)`, Type of `table2.mycolumn` is `Number(6)`. What can I do to join them without Oracle throwing an Error?

Comment: I mean, without performing Operations that change the data definition

Comment: Just join them, there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: I expect @ughai was talking about `CAST()`, as in: `CAST(table2.mycolumn number(10))`. Except I think it's irrelevant in this case. Assuming that the `table1.mycolumn = table2.column` is a typo, and you meant `table1.mycolumn = table2.mycolumn`, that is.

Comment: you can substr mycolumn from table1 to length 6, but it won't guarantee that you will get the right result

Comment: and also cast number value of 6+ length to 6 will cause ORA-01438) so only substr

Comment: Ok, it turned out that the problem did not have anything to do with different sizes, but the database just throws an `ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [19004], [], [], [], [], [], [],`

Answer (score 3):

There is no error doing this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1e4af/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  num_a NUMBER(6)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  num_b NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ( 123456 );
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ( 123456 );
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ( 1234567890 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from table_a a
     join table_b b
     on a.num_a = b.num_b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1e4af/1/0)**:

```
|  NUM_A |  NUM_B |
|--------|--------|
| 123456 | 123456 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you'll get an error? Did you try it?

```
create table t1 (col1 number(10));

create table t2 (col1 number(6));

insert into t1
select 1000000001 col1 from dual union all
select 1111111 col1 from dual union all
select 1 col1 from dual;

insert into t2
select 111111 col1 from dual union all
select 1 col1 from dual;

commit;

select *
from   t1 inner join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1);

      COL1     COL1_1
---------- ----------
         1          1
```